# Can anyone help me simplify the following code?

Tags: python, simplify

I'm attempting to reduce the redundancy within my code. If anyone can provide suggestions I would appreciate it. Below is the code I have in python. I understand that the input is used three times and is not necessary but I can't get the code to work without it. If anyone has experience with importing modules in an easier manner and would like to assist, I would also appreciate that.

```
#  import Mylib to satisfy requirements 1 and 2
from Mylib import scalc


# Added try except to lowRange and highRange user input
while True:
    lowRange = int(input('lowRange:'))
    highRange = int(input('highRange:'))
    try:
        firstNumber = int(input('firstNumber:'))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must type a number between lowRange and highRange")
    else:
        if (firstNumber >= lowRange) and (firstNumber < highRange):
            print("You entered: ", firstNumber)
        else:
            print("The number you entered is incorrect!")
    try:
        secondNumber = int(input('secondNumber:'))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must type a number between lowRange and highRange")
    else:
        if (secondNumber > lowRange) and (secondNumber < highRange):
            print("You entered: ", secondNumber)
        else:
            print("The number you entered is incorrect!")
    print("firstNumber=", firstNumber)
    print("secondNumber=", secondNumber)
    add = (firstNumber + secondNumber)
    print("The result of " + str(firstNumber), "+", str(secondNumber), "=", add)
    sub = (firstNumber - secondNumber)
    print("The result of " + str(firstNumber), "-", str(secondNumber), "=", sub)
    mult = (firstNumber * secondNumber)
    print("The result of " + str(firstNumber), "*", str(secondNumber), "=", mult)
    div = (firstNumber / secondNumber)
    print("The result of " + str(firstNumber), "/", str(secondNumber), "=", div)
    print()

    yn = input("Continue using calculator? y/n ->")
    if yn == "y":
        continue
    else:
        print("Thanks for using my calculator!")
        break

##Module to import##
# Get two numbers from user
# define functions for each operation

lowRange = int(input('lowRange:'))
highRange = int(input('highRange:'))
firstNumber = int(input('firstNumber:'))

def add(firstNumber, secondNumber, ):
    return firstNumber + secondNumber


def sub(firstNumber, secondNumber, ):
    return firstNumber - secondNumber


def mult(firstNumber, secondNumber, ):
    return firstNumber * secondNumber


def div(firstNumber, secondNumber):
    return firstNumber / secondNumber

# range function
def isinrange(lr, hr, n):
    lr = lowRange
    hr = highRange
    n = firstNumber
    if n > lr and n < hr:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def scalc(p1):
    astring = p1.split(",")
    firstNumber = float(astring[0])
    secondNumber = float(astring[1])
    if astring[2] == "+":
        add(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    elif astring[2] == "-":
        sub(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    elif astring[2] == "*":
        mult(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    elif astring[2] == "/":
        div(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    return firstNumber, secondNumber
p1 = input("select two numbers and operator")
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. We here on Stack Overflow are here to help answer specific programming questions. However, the people on the code review Stack Exchange site would probably be happy to help you out. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ If you are unsure how to write a good question, you can always check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Locke, the question needs a lot of work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The key to reducing redundancy is to look at the things you're doing over and over, and turn them into functions (or find an existing function that can do that *type of thing*).

Inputting numbers with error handling is the type of thing that makes sense to break out into its own function with its own `while` loop that will repeat until a valid number is entered.

You can also potentially make use of `for` loops and `functools.reduce` to eliminate some copying and pasting -- it doesn't make much of a difference in terms of the overall number of lines of code with only two variables, but it does eliminate duplication, and it allows you to very easily add a third variable by just changing a single line of code:

```
from functools import reduce

def input_range() -> range:
    while True:
        try:
            r = range(
                int(input("lowRange: ")), 
                int(input("highRange: ")) + 1
            )
            if not r:
                raise ValueError("highRange must be greater than lowRange")
            return r
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)


def input_number(name: str, bound: range) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(f"{name}: "))
            if n not in bound:
                raise ValueError(
                    "You must type a number between lowRange and highRange"
                )
            return n
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)


funcs = {
    "+": int.__add__,
    "-": int.__sub__,
    "*": int.__mul__,
    "/": int.__truediv__,
}

while True:
    bound = input_range()
    numbers = {
        name: input_number(name, bound)
        for name in ("firstNumber", "secondNumber")  # try adding "thirdNumber"!
    }
    for name, number in numbers.items():
        print(f"{name}={number}")
    for symbol, func in funcs.items():
        expr = symbol.join(map(str, numbers.values()))
        result = reduce(func, numbers.values())
        print(f"The result of {expr}={result}")

    if input("Continue using calculator? y/n ->") != "y":
        print("Thanks for using my calculator!")
        break
```